# proofs of independence

Tags: logic

If we have a first-order theory, do all independence proofs of a certain result in that theory need to use "outside" assumptions?

Cant we just enumerate all proofs in that theory and conclude that none of them leads to our result?

Consider following: we have the axioms that we can change MUI into MIU and MIU into MUI. Is the question: "Can we change MUI into IMU?" undecidable in the system?

Comment: There are consistent formal theories of arithmetic (necessarily weak) which prove their own consistency (see Dan Willard's result [here](http://www.cs.albany.edu/~dew/m/jsl1.pdf)).  It is conceivable (though I am by no means certain) that such a theory could prove independence results about itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, in the last paragraph of the question, you intended (though you didn't explicitly say so) that the only available symbols are M, I, and U, then the fact that you can't change MUI to IMU is not only not provable in the system but not even statable in the system, because the system doesn't contain words like "change".

Comment: I see. So the statement "MUI can be changed to MIU" also cannot be stated in the logic, then?

Comment: @Adam That's right; the only things that can be stated in the logic you described are strings of M's, U's, and I's, nothing resembling English sentences.

Answer (score 2):

If you would just somehow so simply just enumerate all theorems in a given theory, and then somehow so simply just check if any given statement belongs to that (usually infinite) list or not, then you can very easily decide what the theory decides and what it does not. Of course, the problem is that this is rarely the case.